# How to fix "Failed to instantiate a processor of type '"Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Processing.EventProcessor"'"

Tags: marketing-automation

Marketing Automation is not working. When I check log in **[xconnect]\Website\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Logs**
I have found this below error:
    **Failed to instantiate a processor of type '"Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Processing.EventProcessor"'**

```
2018-05-17 10:37:19.698 +03:00 [Error] Failed to instantiate a processor of type '"Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Processing.EventProcessor"'.
System.InvalidOperationException: This configuration has not been initialized. Please call the initialize method before using it.
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.CheckInitialized()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.get_CurrentModel()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext..ctor(XdbContextConfiguration configuration)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient..ctor(XConnectClientConfiguration config)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationServiceType.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<op_Implicit>b__0(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseServiceDecorator>b__1(IServiceProvider provider)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ServiceProvider )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationServiceType.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<op_Implicit>b__0(IServiceProvider sp)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ServiceProvider )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationServiceType.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<op_Implicit>b__0(IServiceProvider sp)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ServiceProvider )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Factory.ProcessorFactory.CreateProcessor(Guid contactId, ExecutionData data)
```

I have searched a lot but don't find anything related to fixing this issue.

Comment: anything more in the log?

Comment: updated log info

Comment: Do you have any custom models configured or any other customizations?

Comment: We have some custom facet but that is not related to marketing automation.

Comment: @AnikSaha Please check log files for the xconnect instances (collection + search)

Comment: @anik - Did you get a fix for this error as i am facing the same issue.

Comment: in my case the problem was missing permissions to read ssl certificate (used for the xconnect) for Local Service which is running the automation index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the `SSL certificate` of `{website}.xconnect` in IIS.
Also please check the license file of .`\Website\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data and thumbprint` of .`\Website\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config file`. There might be some problem there.

Comment: Yeah there was expired license.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me on this issue was to grant permission to IISUser on the xConnect certificate.

Steps:

- Right click on certificate
- Click on manage private keys and grant permission to IISUser.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I checked Event Viewer and there were two "strange" errors:

ISAPI Filter `'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\\\aspnet_filter.dll' could not be loaded due to a configuration problem`

`Could not load all ISAPI filters for site 'SITECORE911.XCONNECT'.`  Therefore site startup aborted.

I don't know-how but in IIS the path to ISAPI filter was with two slashes

```
v4.0.30319\\\\aspnet_filter.dll
```

instead of

```
v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll
```

This was my solution. This fixed XConnect site, it started to run and error "This configuration has not been initialized. Please call the initialize method before using it" disappeared due to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 11 you may also face the issue reported on this post with the solution

https://blog.martinmiles.net/post/troubleshooting-marketing-automation-service-start-for-xp-10-2-installation-on-windows-11

Comment: That is link only answer - copy base information from the blog post into the answer and keep source link so one can get more details if needed.