# Failed to start service 'Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine

Tags: sitecore-commerce, azure, sitecore-install-framework, marketing-automation

I am getting error

```
"Failed to start service 'Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine - gettingStartedxconnect.dev.local-MarketingAutomationService (gettingStartedxconnect.dev.local-MarketingAutomationService)'."
```

I did all the steps/solutions provided in the various posts but still, I am getting this error. Below are environment and application, services errors.

```
Environment - Azure VM, Windows 11 Pro N, 64 Bit, 32 GB RAM, AMD EPYC 7763 64-Core Processor                   2.44 GHz
```

Thanks in advance.

**Application log error is as below:**

```
Faulting application name: Sitecore.MAEngine.exe, version: 8.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xda34621d
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.22000.708, time stamp: 0x89f799f7
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000004474c
Faulting process id: 0x1a80
Faulting application start time: 0x01d887d2210092d4
Faulting application path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\gettingStartedxconnect.dev.local\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\Sitecore.MAEngine.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 80cec838-b8e0-4296-99ac-2eb7f391b0e3
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

------------------------------------
Application: Sitecore.MAEngine.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.CheckInitialized()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.get_CurrentModel()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.FactoryCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSiteMain(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverLock)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSite(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider, System.Type, System.Object[])
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.FactoryCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSiteMain(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverLock)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSite(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider, System.Type, System.Object[])
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.FactoryCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSiteMain(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverLock)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSite(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider, System.Type, System.Object[])
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions+<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<UseServiceDecorator>b__1(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.FactoryCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSiteMain(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverLock)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSite(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider, System.Type, System.Object[])
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.FactoryCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSiteMain(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSite(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IEnumerableCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSiteMain(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitNoCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSite(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider, System.Type, System.Object[])
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.FactoryCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSiteMain(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverLock)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSite(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.IServiceProvider)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.ServiceConfiguration.get_Engine()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.EngineService.OnStart(System.String[])
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[])
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.Program.RunAsService()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.Program.Main(System.String[])`
```

---

### When tried to start the services manually, I get below error:

### Services

```
Windows could not start the Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine - gettingStartedxconnect.dev.local-MarketingAutomationService service on Local Computer.
    
    
    
Error 1064: An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request.
```

---

OK
---------------------------

Comment: Did you check this link: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11832/how-to-fix-failed-to-instantiate-a-processor-of-type-sitecore-xdb-marketingau

Comment: Did you check the un-signed certificates by using this command? 

`Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject}`

Comment: Did you try this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32149/error-while-installing-sitecore-10-2-sitecore-xconnect-xdbcollectionunavailable/32150?noredirect=1

Comment: We had same issue while installing `Sitecore 10.2`. Indeed, Sitecore Stack Exchange has lot of solutions for this similar issue(thanks for all bloggers). But you have to identify the root cause before apply prompt solution. Below stack exchange answer helps you. `https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27214/sitecore-9-3-installation-failing-failed-to-start-the-marketing-automation-en/31970#31970`

Comment: For those who are still looking for answer: 
Disable TLS 1.3 over TCP for xconnect worked for me, Remember I got this error for Windows 11. On Windows 10 installation worked fine for me.  Thanks to Martin for providing the script to disable TLS 1.3 (https://blog.martinmiles.net/post/troubleshooting-marketing-automation-service-start-for-xp-10-2-installation-on-windows-11)